# Given $1 + 2^{1/2} + 3^{1/3} + \dots + 100^{1/100}$ lies strictly between 111 and 112, show it is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My title completely describes the question. I tried to look at the polynomial $$p(x) = (x-1)(x-2^{1/2})\dots (x-100^{1/100})$$ since the sum naturally appears as the coefficient of $x^{99}$, and then tried examining $p$ at a few values like $1, 99 \ \& 100$, but didn't seem to be useful. My guess is that the numbers $111$ and $112$ don't really matter but the fact that the sum is not an integer may be essential. Any hints?

Comment: What is the question? To show $1+2^{1/2}+\dots+100^{1/100}$ is irrational?

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes.

Comment: By the way, the title does not completely describe the question. A demand to solve a problem is not a question.

Comment: Look up algebraic integers

Comment: @Empy2 I am familiar with algebraic integers. How would you use them?

Comment: Each term is the root of a polynomial with integer coefficients and leading coefficient 1, so their sum is too.  The denominator of any rational root of a polynomial is a factor of the leading coefficient

Comment: @Empy2 Thanks, I get it now.

Comment: @erdoswiles said another way, the sum of algebraic integers is an algebraic integer, and the only rational algebraic integers are integers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following Empy2's comment, here is a solution. Since $n^{1/n}$ is a root of $x^n - n$, $n^{1/n}$ is an algebraic integer for $n = 1,2,\dots,100$. Since the algebraic integers form a ring, their sum is also an algebraic integer. Because we know from the rational roots theorem that $\mathbb{Z}_\mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Z}$, and since the real number $1 + 2^{1/2} + \dots + 100^{1/100}$ is not an integer, it must be an irrational number.